# Set Multiple Notification Emails in Preferences?

Tags: feature-request, email

We can have multiple email addresses that we log in from; however, I can't seem to figure out how to set multiple emails for my Notification Email(s). It should ideally send notifications to all emails I can log in from!

How do you set multiple emails for your notification emails?

If there is no way to set multiple emails for notification emails then I suggest this functionality be implemented! If there is a way, a tool tip to show how to do it would be nice.

Comment: For the record, you (can) sign in with an OAuth provide, like Google, not necessarily an email account.

Comment: @gunr2171 I know; however, we can also log in from two different email addresses (as I have two email addresses that I log in from)

Comment: Can't you have one email forward SO emails to the other accounts?

Comment: its certainly a possible work around and I did think about it; however, it would be a lot more simple if they allowed you receive notification emails from two accounts.

Answer (score 2):

I... don't really understand why this is even remotely desirable. Regardless, it's probably something you should work out on your end - we probably don't need to be sending more duplicate emails.